# How to do implement search in expandable list from app bar in android

Tags: java, android

I have an expandable list of names. I am able to implement search through `SearchView` widget and `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener`. I want to implement same functionality with

`<searchable> ... </searchable>` configuration. I want to attach same kind of listener as of SearchView to get query and filter data. How to do that with `<searchable>`

[image: searchbar]

I have following following files.

manifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".ContactListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCompatTheme">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

saved_tabs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

    <!--<SearchView android:id="@+id/search" android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
        <!--android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:iconifiedByDefault="false" />-->

    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:indicatorLeft="300dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

searchable.xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

options_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

ContactListActivity.java

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
```

and

SavedTabFragment.java

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.saved_tabes, null);
        ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

        Map<String,Object> contactDetails = getContacts();
        final List<String> names = (List<String>)contactDetails.get("names");
        final List<List<String>> numbers = (List<List<String>>)contactDetails.get("numbers");
        expandableListAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(names, numbers,getActivity());
        elv.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: `I want to implement same functionality with <searchable> ... </searchable> configuration` what do you actually mean?

Comment: I dont want to use custom SearchView for search box. I want to use searchable.xml configuration

Comment: if you dont want to use custom SearchView, so what view do you want to use for your search?